# one column two times in WHERE condition

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have an important question. I need to use a column two times in `WHERE` condition.

Example is here:

```
SELECT COL1 as salary, COL1 as money
FROM employees
WHERE salary = '3000' OR money = '5000'
```

How can I restrict the same column twice? I need a simple solution. Better with alias. Thank you

Comment: is you salary and money diffrent column  ???

Comment: What is the **real** issue?

Comment: your query is right I pasted another solution where you dont have to specify column name 2 times I hipe this is what you are looking for

Comment: I pasted my answer please check if this is what you need

Comment: Hello Yashveer Singh thanks for the question.  No salary and money ist the same column.

Comment: @Yves I answered you question please check my answer if my answer is fine then please accept it if you have any question then ask about my answer

Comment: Hello  Dudu Markovitz i Need two columns (Salary and Money ) as result. These columns come from a single column COL1.

Answer (score 1):

When a `SELECT` statement is processed, the `WHERE` clause is processed before the `SELECT` clause. This means that, when the `WHERE` clause is processed, the aliases (which are defined in `SELECT`) don't exist yet. The query the way you wrote it will fail with a syntax error message, something like "unknown identifier."

Since what you are really filtering on is the value in `col1`, why do you care if it is using the column name `col1` or an alias? Somehow I get the impression that your problem is different and you over-simplified it to the point that it no longer makes sense.

In any case: with what you have shown (which, again, may not be your *real* problem), you can write the `WHERE` condition either as

```
where col1 = 3000 or col1 = 5000
```

(assuming `col1` is of `number` data type - there's no reason to compare to strings like `'3000'` and `'5000'`), or as

```
where col1 in (3000, 5000)
```

Comment: Thanks @mathguy. Your answer is very helpfull. I think i can solve my problem :)